# SOQL Sub Query is not working

Tags: soql

I'm trying to retrieve a MAX Date from an SOQL query, using the WHERE CLAUSE. I can accomplish this in Oracle using the following SQL syntax:

```
Select LastModifiedDate FROM Opportunity A
WHERE LastModifiedDate = (Select MAX(LastModifiedDate) from Opportunity B)
```

How can I accomplish the same task in SOQL using the WHERE clause?

Please Help!

Ny

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as to what you're trying to achieve here, but if you just want the most recent last modified date in the Opportunities object you could do this:

`select Id, LastModifiedDate from Opportunity order by LastModifiedDate desc limit 1`